# Creating iOS widgets in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, widget

How do we create iOS widgets using react native? I've tried using react-native-shared-group-preferences plugin to connect the native code with RN. But still I'm having some doubt regarding customising widgets and updating widget data based on API response

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-native-today-widget](https://github.com/matejkriz/react-native-today-widget/)

But be aware that The memory limit of a Today widget is 16 MB.
for more info check [App-extensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/app-extensions)